# Convert files in a folder to pdf

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, filesystems, xlsxwriter

I am trying to finish a program that converts excel files to pdf in a folder. I am having issues with the file names. This is what I have so far. Any help on how to complete it would be appreciated.

```
import win32com.client, types, pythoncom, sys, os, string 
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
for file in os.listdir("C:\Users\Desktop\ExcelFiles"):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        fileName = file
        books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\ExcelFiles"  + str(fileName))
        ws = books.Worksheets[0]
        ws.Visible = 1
        fileName.replace(".xlsx","")
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "C:\Users\Desktop\PDF\" + str(fileName) + ".pdf")
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"issues with the file names"*? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: maybe you need to use raw string `r`,  `r"C:\Users\Desktop\PDF\" + str(fileName) + ".pdf"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is this line:

```
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\ExcelFiles"  + str(fileName))
```

Your most likely missing a trailing slash after ExcelFiles:

```
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\ExcelFiles\"  + str(fileName))
```

Python provides the cross-platform `os.path.join` function for cases like this. It will join path strings with the correct platform-specific slash:

```
filepath = os.path.join("C:\Users\Desktop\ExcelFiles", fileName)
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
```

Hope that helps. If this isn't the answer, you'll want to include the traceback you're getting in your question above. Right now, there isn't enough information to answer your question with confidence.